# how to improve tagging on a question about "short version of emph"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

[this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40513/short-version-of-emph) asking for a "short version of emph", e.g. `|text|` is tagged as just "emphasis", but it's really about more than that.  "macro" and "catcodes" aren't really appropriate.  "define" or "shorthand" might be, but no such tags exist; besides, "define" (or "definition") would logically be a synonym for "macro", and "shorthand" might be too restrictive.  but the cited question is a good one, and deserves a better chance to be found.

suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using [syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax), additionally [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros).

Comment: I added these two tags to {emphasis}.